# How can I populate ASPX Textbox controls using a SQL Inner Join statement in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

My intention is to populate textbox controls on an ASPX page using a SQL Inner Join.  One textbox control(txtContactNum) is to be populated from my CompanyContacts table, while the other two textboxes(txtCity, txtURL) are to be populated from the Companies table. 
Here are the SQL Inner Join statements I have tried in the btnSelectCompany Event Handler:

1. comm = new SqlCommand("Select CompanyContacts.ContactNum, Companies.CompanyNum, Companies.CompanyName, Companies.City, Companies.URL  FROM Companies INNER JOIN CompanyContacts ON CompanyNum = @CompanyNum;", conn);
2. comm = new SqlCommand("Select Companies.CompanyNum, Companies.CompanyName, Companies.City, Companies.URL CompanyContacts.ContactNum FROM Companies, CompanyContacts WHERE CompanyNum = @CompanyNum", conn);
3. comm = new SqlCommand("Select CompanyName, City, URL FROM Companies WHERE CompanyNum = @CompanyNum", conn);

   ```
   <asp:Calendar ID="calDateOfPosting" SelectionMode="Day" ShowGridLines="True" OnSelectionChanged="DateSelection_Change" runat="server">
       <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="Yellow" ForeColor="Red"></SelectedDayStyle>
   </asp:Calendar>
   <span class="widelabel">Date Of Posting:</span>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateOfPosting" runat="server" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <span class="widelabel">Company:</span>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCompanies" runat="server">
   </asp:DropDownList>

   <asp:Button ID="btnSelectCompany" Text="Select Company" runat="server" 
       onclick="btnSelectCompany_Click" />     
   <br />
   <br />
   <span class="widelabel">Contact Number:</span>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtContactNum" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <span class="widelabel">Job Type:</span>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlJobType" runat="server">
       <asp:ListItem>Software/Development</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>Networking</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
   <br />
   <br />
   <span class="widelabel">Posting Source:</span>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPostingSource" runat="server">
       <asp:ListItem>Select Posting Source</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>NEIT</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>Web Search Engines</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>Tech Collective</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
   <br />
   <br />
   <span class="widelabel">Description:</span>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <span class="widelabel">City:</span>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <span class="widelabel">URL:</span>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtURL" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <span class="widelabel">Attachment:</span>
   <%--<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />--%>
   <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
   <br />
   <br />

   <span class="widelabel">Cover Letter Submitted?:</span>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCoverLetter" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Letter" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server">
       <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
   <br />
   <br />
   <asp:Panel ID="pnlLetter" runat="server">
   <p><b>Date Cover Letter Submitted:</b></p>
   <asp:Calendar ID="calCLDateSubmitted"  SelectionMode="Day" ShowGridLines="True" OnSelectionChanged="CLDateSubmitted_Change" runat="server">
       <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="Yellow" ForeColor="Red"></SelectedDayStyle>       
   </asp:Calendar>
   <span class="widelabel">Date Of Submission:</span>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtCLDateSubmitted" runat="server" />
   </asp:Panel>

   <span class="widelabel">Resume Submitted?:</span>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlResume" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Resume" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server">
       <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
   <br />
   <br />
   <asp:Panel ID="pnlResume" runat="server">
   <p><b>Date Resume Submitted:</b></p>
   <asp:Calendar ID="calRDateSubmitted"  SelectionMode="Day" ShowGridLines="True" OnSelectionChanged="RDateSubmitted_Change" runat="server">
       <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="Yellow" ForeColor="Red"></SelectedDayStyle>       
   </asp:Calendar>
   <span class="widelabel">Date Of Submission:</span>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtRDateSubmitted" runat="server" />
   </asp:Panel>
   <br />
   <br />
   <span class="widelabel">Comments:</span>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <br />
   <br />
   ```

   ---

   ---

Below is the C# business logic

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;

public partial class JobPostings_JobPostings : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        pnlLetter.Visible = false;
        pnlResume.Visible = false;
        LoadCompanies();
    }

}


private void LoadCompanies()
{

    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm;
    SqlDataReader reader;

    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["jobSearchDB"].ConnectionString;
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    comm = new SqlCommand("Select CompanyNum,CompanyName FROM Companies", conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();


        ddlCompanies.DataSource = reader;
        ddlCompanies.DataValueField = "CompanyNum";
        ddlCompanies.DataTextField = "CompanyName";
        ddlCompanies.DataBind();
        reader.Close();


    } // End of Try Block
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblErrorLabel.Text = "The Following Errors ocurred during the Data Read process: ";
        lblErrorLabel.Text += ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    } // End of Finally Block

    ClearFormClass clearForm = new ClearFormClass();
    clearForm.ClearWebFormControls1(pnlAddJobPosting);
} // End of LoadCompanies()

protected void btnSelectCompany_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm;
    SqlDataReader reader;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["jobSearchDB"].ConnectionString;
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    // Create a SQL Query with an Inner Join for tables Companies and CompanyContacts so that CITY and URL can be returned from Companies, and ContactNum can be returned from CompanyContacts
// I have listed the SQL Queries which I have tried below. 

    comm = new SqlCommand("Select CompanyContacts.ContactNum, Companies.CompanyNum, Companies.CompanyName, Companies.City, Companies.URL  FROM Companies INNER JOIN CompanyContacts ON CompanyNum = @CompanyNum;", conn);
    comm = new SqlCommand("Select Companies.CompanyNum, Companies.CompanyName, Companies.City, Companies.URL CompanyContacts.ContactNum FROM Companies, CompanyContacts WHERE CompanyNum = @CompanyNum", conn);
comm = new SqlCommand("Select CompanyName, City, URL FROM Companies WHERE CompanyNum = @CompanyNum", conn);

    comm.Parameters.Add("@CompanyNum", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    comm.Parameters["@CompanyNum"].Value = ddlCompanies.SelectedItem.Value;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {

            txtContactNum.Text = reader["ContactNum"].ToString();
            txtCity.Text = reader["City"].ToString();
            txtURL.Text = reader["URL"].ToString();

        } // End of IF Block
        reader.Close();

        btnClear.Enabled = true;
        btnCancel.Enabled = true;

    } // End of Try Block
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblErrorLabel.Text = "Error Loading The Company Information For The Job Posting.<br />";
        lblErrorLabel.Text += ex.Message.ToString();
    } // End of Catch Block
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
} // End of btnSelectCompany_Click
```

[image]

Comment: What in your current attempt isn't working?  Also, why do you over-write the `comm` variable three times?

Comment: `"In my code, only one is uncommented."` - Look again, you didn't comment out those lines.  As for the error, that's an error coming from SQL.  So the first thing you're going to want to do is determine which SQL query you're actually executing.  Narrow down to *just* that SQL code and look for the syntax error.

Comment: Hi David, I listed the three comm objects in my post. In my code, only one is uncommented. The first comm object throws no errors, but also does  not populate any of the three textboxes. The second comm object throws an Exception  error message; Incorrect syntax near '.'.  The third comm object populates the City and URL textbox controls, but not the Contact Number textbox. I Know in the example, I provided, NONE of the three are commented out. In my compiled code, I only use one at a time. Thanks.

Comment: Deleting your comment and re-posting it again doesn't make it *more true*.  Look at the code you've posted.  ***All three*** lines are uncommented.  If the code you have on your computer is *different* from the code in the post, how do you expect anybody here to help you?  As for the error, the second query has a typo (you forgot a comma in the list of fields), and the third one doesn't select a "contact number" so clearly it won't have a "contact number".

Comment: David, first of all, thank you for your feedback. Secondly, I deleted my first reply because my edits timed-out. So, I deleted it and added more information. As for the third comm object not returning the Contact Number, I know this. That comm object was used to incrementally populate textboxes. I used it to determine that my parameterized query was working. I will continue to work on this. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From comments on the question...

> Incorrect syntax near '.'

You have a typo in your query:

```
Select Companies.CompanyNum, Companies.CompanyName, Companies.City, Companies.URL CompanyContacts.ContactNum FROM ...
```

Note the missing comma between the last two fields in the `SELECT` list.  Selected fields need to be separated by a comma:

```
Select Companies.CompanyNum, Companies.CompanyName, Companies.City, Companies.URL, CompanyContacts.ContactNum FROM ...
                                                                         here ---^
```

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL statement works. (comm = new SqlCommand("Select Companies.CompanyNum, Companies.City, Companies.URL, CompanyContacts.ContactNum FROM Companies, CompanyContacts WHERE Companies.CompanyNum = @CompanyNum", conn);)It is listed as the second SQL statement in my abstract at the top of this post. The reason it did not work initially was because I was pointing to a database that did not contain any data in the CompanyContacts table.